# How to do base calculations without pow in C++?

Tags: c++, radix, pow

**Below is the problem. But I can`t use pow or print. We learned only if, loops and cout so far.**

Using a for loop, write code that will compute the result of an int raised to the power of another int. For example, your for loop should use two variables, one for the base and one for the exponent. It should then calculate the base raised to the exponent. 2 raised to the power of 2 should output 4, 2 raised to 8 should output 256, etc. Ensure your code meets these requirements and then paste it in the response section below:

Contains a variable for the base
Contains a variable for the exponent
Uses a for loop to perform the power function
Outputs the result to the console window

I went as far as this but couldn`t figure out how to do base calculations. I just get 4 when I run it

```
int n = 3;
int p = 4;
int e = 1;
int i = 1;
for (i = 1; i <= p; i++)
{
    e = e * n;
}
cout << p;
```

Edit: I figured it out and made it like this

```
int base {2};
int exponent {10};
int output {1};

for(int i=0; i<exponent; i++)
{
    output *= base;
}
std::cout << output << "\n";
```

Comment: What does stepping through the code in a debugger tell you might be going wrong?

Comment: I changed the cout to e but now, The result shows 81 though. I need the base of the number to be multiplied like 4*4*4*4 if it`s p.    Debugger doesn`t show me any error

Comment: It seems you either want to calculate 3^4 = 3*3*3*3 or 4^3 = 4*4*4. Please shed more light about your issue.

Comment: The debugger will show you exactly what's wrong if you step through the code and inspect the variables as each line executes.

Comment: I just need to do that I wrote in the initial question above. But I right now I`m getting 81 which is not the results for anything I`m looking for

Comment: what's with the weird initialization? Also put your answer as an answer please.

Answer (score 2):

you need to cout<< e!
You are printing p which is always 4!

Comment: Fixed. Now, The result shows 81 though. I need the base of the number to be multiplied like 4*4*4*4 if it`s p

Comment: @CryptoBoy um...  3^4 is 81 (you'e  code computes n^p)

Comment: Oh I see now. I think this will do it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Well gonna take a wild guess but you should use

```
cout << e;
```

You are priting the wrong variable :p. The code you have should work fine.

Comment: Fixed. Now, The result shows 81 though. I need the base of the number to be multiplied like 4*4*4*4 if it`s p